# ASP.NET Core MVC List<Model>.Contains(Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I have this class:

```
public class UserSet
{
    public int One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string Three { get; set; }
}
```

And a static class:

```
public static class AllUsers
{
    public static List<UserSet> Usersc = new List<UserSet>();
}
```

I always create new `UserSet` and then store it in `Usersc`. Basically I do this:

```
Data.UserSet setupSet = new Data.UserSet()
        {
            One = name,
            Two = OsCislo,
            Three = User.Identity.Name
        };
```

Then I store it.

```
Data.AllUsers.Usersc.Add(setupSet)
```

Now what I want to do is:

1. Define setupSet
2. Check if setupSet is in Usersc.
3. If one (from my setupSet) is in Usersc then
   3a) if setupSet is in Userc and everything is equal then don't do anything.
   3b) If something is different then delete old UserSet in AllUsers and insert the new one

In code it will look like this:

```
Data.UserSet setupSet = new Data.UserSet()
        {
            One = name,
            Two = OsCislo,
            Three = User.Identity.Name
        };

if (Data.AllUsers.Usersc.Select(s => s.One).ToList().Contains(User.Identity.Name))
{
    // Always returns false for some reason
    if (!Data.AllUser.Usersc.Contains(setupSet))
    {
        Data.AllUsers.Usersc.Remove(Data.AllUsers.Usersc.Where(s => s.One == User.Identity.Name).ToList().First());
        Data.AllUsers.Usersc.Add(setupSet);
    }
}
else
{
    Data.AllUsers.Usersc.Add(setupSet);
}
```

As you can see, problem is in my if statement where I try to get whether setupSet is inside Usersc but for some odd reason it always returns false even though setupSet should be inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your line of code Data.AllUser.Usersc.Contains(setupSec) compares references - not values of the properties of objects in the list.

You create your setupSet object at the top without adding it to the list - so this list doesn't contain it. Despite the fact that two objects have exactly the same values of properties for .net these are two different objects. Therefore list.Contains() return false.

So to solve your problem there are 2 ways:

1. Don't use Contains() method of List - and use LINQ expression comparing properties that are crucial for your understanding equality of 2 objects of your UserSet class
2. Definitely better - implement Equals method inside your UserSet class that will tell the CLI what do you understand as EQUAL if it comes to your class.

Take a look at the following code (please bear in mind that this is a naive implementation):

```
void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<SomeClass>();

    var o1 = new SomeClass{SomeProperty = "foo"};

    myList.Add(o1);

    var o2 = new SomeClass{SomeProperty = "foo"};

    if(myList.Contains(o2))
    {
        "List Contains element".Dump();
    }
    else{
        "List does not contain element".Dump();
    }

}



private class SomeClass{
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var casted = obj as SomeClass;
        if(casted == null) return false;
        if(string.Equals(casted.SomeProperty, this.SomeProperty)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here I told the .NET what it means for me that 2 instances of my SomeClass are equal by overriding the {public bool Equals(object obj)} method.

Inside of that method I write that 2 objects are equal if value of SomeProperty is the same.

```
if(string.Equals(casted.SomeProperty, this.SomeProperty)) return true;
```

Therefore in the console, I can see "List Contains element". If you remove that override Equal the console will say "List does not contain the element".

Last but not least as Blindy wrote - use thread-safe collection. It will make your example better (however I don't believe that threads are the problem that you described).

You can also dive deeper into in-memory database in Entity Framework - you will not have to create that static class with a static collection of elements (which is a mock of database of cache I believe). It is super-easy

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "My_DB")
                    .Options;
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for solving it! I tried to solve it for like 2 days now.

Answer (score 0):

> even tho setupSet should be inside it

There's a reason `static` is rarely used in Asp.Net projects, of any kind: there are multiple threads that handle your requests, and if they're all fighting over the same `List<>`, that's a recipe for disaster.

Either use a synchronized collection (like `ConcurrentSet<>` or `ConcurrentBag<>`), or use a crude locking mechanism, or *something* to make sure you don't trample one thread's list access from another.

Or even better, use a database to store data. That's what it's made for, and most DBMS are transactional, so they handle multi-threaded access safely for you.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will try to implement something like this.